# Protocol type from IIS binding using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

Is there any way to get only the protocol type from IIS binding using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) can help with this task:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebBinding
```

Results:

```
protocol                                                    bindingInformation
--------                                                    ------------------
http                                                        *:80:
```

If you want just the protocol, you can use the following:

```
Get-WebBinding | Select protocol
```